# File format .dwg/.dxf is missing in save type windows 10

Tags: file, export, sketchup, dxf, dwg

I am using SketchUp to draw a design and tried to export in 2D graphic

While exporting the file, the required format (.dwg/.dxf) is missing on the save type list.

[image]

I have already installed AutoCAD in my system.

The same functionality was working fine till last week, but now it disappeared from the save type list.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using Sketchup 2017 MAKE,(the free version of sketchup). Dxf and Dwg is authorized in Skethup PRO ( the paid version)